# RNN-Generator output shape

Tags: tensorflow, sequence, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to create an sequential generator which can take a protein sequencea and a latent vector to generate smiles sequences, I want the generator to output the full sequence equal to the variable max_smi_len = 110 however it is only able to output a single atom every time I try to generate a random sample.

here is my generator

```
def generator(latent_dim, num_protein_tokens, num_smiles_tokens, max_protein_seq_length, max_smiles_length):
    input_latent = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='input_latent')
    input_protein = Input(shape=(max_protein_seq_length,), name='input_protein')
    embedding_protein = Embedding(num_protein_tokens, 50, mask_zero=True, input_length=max_protein_seq_length)(input_protein)
    lstm_protein = LSTM(256)(embedding_protein)
    concat_layer = Concatenate()([input_latent, lstm_protein])
    lstm_combined = LSTM(5*num_smiles_tokens, input_shape=(latent_dim+256,))(tf.expand_dims(concat_layer, axis=1))
    output_smiles = Dense(num_smiles_tokens, activation='softmax', name='output_smiles')(lstm_combined)
    gen_model = Model(inputs =[input_latent, input_protein], outputs = output_smiles, name='generator')
    return gen_model
generator_model = generator(latent_dim, num_protein_tokens, num_smiles_tokens, max_protein_seq_length, max_smiles_length)
```

here is my sampler

```
def generate_random_sample(generator_model, latent_dim, num_protein_tokens, max_protein_seq_length, num_smiles_tokens):
    random_latent_vector = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1, latent_dim))
    random_seed_protein_sequence = np.random.randint(1, num_protein_tokens, size=(1, max_protein_seq_length))
    generated_smiles = generator_model.predict([random_latent_vector, random_seed_protein_sequence])
    predicted_token_indices = np.argmax(generated_smiles, axis=-1)
    predicted_token_indices = np.atleast_1d(predicted_token_indices)
    actual_tokens = [index_to_token_smi[index] for index in predicted_token_indices]

    generated_smiles = ''.join(actual_tokens)
    return generated_smiles
sample = generate_random_sample(generator_model, latent_dim, num_protein_tokens, max_protein_seq_length, num_smiles_tokens)
print("Generated Smiles Sequence:")
print(sample)


1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step
Generated Smiles Sequence:
o
```